# Simulation not outputting anything on LTSpice

Tags: power-electronics

[image]
[image]
[image]

My group is trying to simulate a UPS for a project and this is what we came up with. First picture is the multisim simulation, second the LT spice simulation, and third it is the output. For the LT Spice simulation - What could be wrong in my circuit for having no output in my graph? Or is there a directive I missed? Did I model the LT Spice circuit differently from the multisim circuit?

Comment: In the plot windows, there's no voltages nor currents selected to output. After simulation, you need to go back to the schematic page and move your mouse cursor over the node or component you want to see the voltage/current over time and click it. Did you did that?

Comment: Wow! I see it now! I clicked on the nodes and it showed on the graph. I'm a new user to LT Spice and was so confused. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AntennaGuy Make that an answer and let OP select it.

Comment: @nat3456 While you're at it, add a `1g` resistor to ground from the primary side of the transformer. While LTspice (note the spelling) may not be complaining, *every* node needs a connection to ground, somehow. This is true for all the SPICE's out there. It would also help you in the long term if you followed a tutorial on how to use LTspice. Know the tool you are using.

Answer (score 3):

In the plot windows, there's no voltages nor currents selected to output. After simulation, you need to go back to the schematic page and move your mouse cursor over the node or component you want to see the voltage/current over time and click it.